# React State Update rendering on second click

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've been scratching my head trying to figure this out, tried everything I could think of/found online, no luck.
I retrieve a list from an API when the component mounts, parse it and push it into another array in my state. I've checked the api and it works okay, I get the data, while debugging I see that the logic is running ok, my console logs are triggering as intended. Only issue I see is the render.

I am doing the following call in ComponentDidMount:

```
ScheduleService.getScheduleList().then((response) =>
  response.data.scheduleList.forEach((schedule: any, index: any) =>
    this.state.nodes?.push({
      id: index,
      label: (
        <div onClick={(e) => this.handleScheduleClick(e)}>
          <Tooltip2
            content={
              "Start: " +
              schedule.startTime.utc +
              " Stop: " +
              schedule.stopTime.utc +
              " Type: " +
              schedule.scheduleType
            }
            placement="right"
          >
            {schedule.id}
          </Tooltip2>
        </div>
      ),
      isExpanded: false,
      icon: "document",
    })
  )
);
```

I've tried adding this call in a callback.. no luck. Tried assigning the values to an array and updating the state afterwards, same result.

When I click on the router and enter the page for the first time my tree is not populated.
[Data not rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALsWP.png)

But after I immediately switch back to this page my data renders.

[Data rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Za9e0.png)

I am aware that React updates the component each time the state changes, but I do not understand why it does not happen now.

Also tried running this.forceUpdate(), same result.

Thanks a lot for the help!

EDIT 1:
I've written below the logic that I am using.

```
 public state: IState= {
        nodes: ITreeNode[],
    }
    
    class MyClass extends React.Component<IState> {
    
    public componentDidMount(){
       this.getScheduleList();
    }

   private getScheduleList = () => {
     ScheduleService.getScheduleList().then((response) =>
      response.data.scheduleList.forEach((schedule: any, index: any) =>
        this.state.nodes?.push({
          id: index,
          label: (
            <div onClick={(e) => this.handleScheduleClick(e)}>
              <Tooltip2
                content={
                  "Start: " +
                  schedule.startTime.utc +
                  " Stop: " +
                  schedule.stopTime.utc +
                  " Type: " +
                  schedule.scheduleType
                }
                placement="right"
              >
                {schedule.id}
              </Tooltip2>
            </div>
          ),
          isExpanded: false,
          icon: "document",
        })
      )
    );
    public render() {
        return (
<div>
         <Tree
                      contents={this.state.nodes}
                        className={
                        " focus-panelsList focus-panelsList-noborder"
                      }
                    />
                  </div>
            }
    )
```

Comment: `this.state.nodes.push({})` is a state mutation and `this.setState(this.state)` seems like a useless update. Are you just trying to populate the `this.state.nodes` state? Can you include a more comprehensive code example?

Comment: I've edited the post and added the whole logic for the update method I am attempting. I have an interface for the nodes list and I am pushing the data into that list that I've setup in state. I am passing that node list to a BlueprintJS Tree.

Comment: You really shouldn't store React components in state, it's a sure-fire way to have stale state/callback enclosures. It should be ***just*** the data and then you map the data to JSX when rendering. What are you really trying to do? Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Editing the post now.

Comment: @DrewReese I've updated the code with the logic I am using. Don't think the other code that I have can impact this. As for the JSX part I am using a library and followed their example. As of now I don't see how I can inject that JSX in that Tree, that component is not build by me.

Comment: Create a temporary "temp" array variable inside your API callback and push all elements to that temporary array. After completing the looping DOA this.setState({nodes:temp})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

It seems your issue is state mutation. If you are loading data and populating the `this.state.nodes` state array then you should not pushing into the current state.

Use a functional state update to update from any previously existing state, and append the newly mapped array of empty objects.

Secondly you are storing JSX in state which is a React anti-pattern. You should store ***just*** the data and then later map the state to the JSX you need to pass to the third-party module.

```
ScheduleService.getScheduleList()
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState((prevState: IState) => ({
      nodes: prevState.nodes.concat(response.data),
    }));
  });
```

Mapping state to JSX

```
const data = this.state.nodes.map((schedule: any, index: any) => ({
  id: index,
  label: (
    <div onClick={this.handleScheduleClick}>
      <Tooltip2
        content={
          "Start: " +
          schedule.startTime.utc +
          " Stop: " +
          schedule.stopTime.utc +
          " Type: " +
          schedule.scheduleType
        }
        placement="right"
      >
        {schedule.id}
      </Tooltip2>
    </div>
  ),
  isExpanded: false,
  icon: "document",
}));
```

Pass `data` to the third-party component instead of `this.state.nodes` you were likely previously doing.

On top of this, you also have no initial state. You should provide valid initial state.

```
class MyClass extends React.Component<IState> {
  state = {
    nodes: [],
  };

  public componentDidMount(){
    this.getScheduleList();
  }
```

Comment: I've tried to implement but I get the following error on prevState.nodes: Property 'nodes' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'.ts(2339)

Comment: @EmilianMarin You need to type the `prevState` variable, it's the same as your `this.state`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I've also separated the JSX as you recommended.  As for the state error I mentioned earlier I see now why I got that error. I just started using React with TSX today, keep forgetting I need to declare the type on everything.

Comment: One last questions, where do you recommend keeping that mapping between data and the state? I've declared the const in the render block. Is it a good practice to keep it here? Or maybe should I return it from a method?

Comment: @EmilianMarin It's fine being declared and computed there in the render function. It really comes down to preference if that's ok or if you prefer factoring into a utility function. Either will work and perform about the same.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you cannot edit the state directly. In order to update state and for react to recognize the change in state is by using the `this.setState` method.
Second, you should not store component in the state. You can store data needed to in the state and in the render method of the component use the map function to go through the `nodes` and generate label component.
I've refactored the `getScheduleList` method. 'I've updated it so it sets the nodes to this array instead of updating state at each iteration.

```
private getScheduleList = () => {
  ScheduleService.getScheduleList().then((response) => {
    const nodesData = response.data.scheduleList.map((schedule: any, index: any) => ({
      id: index,
      schedule: schedule,
      label: {
        content: "Start: " +
          schedule.startTime.utc +
          " Stop: " +
          schedule.stopTime.utc +
          " Type: " +
          schedule.scheduleType,
          id: schedule.id,
      },
      isExpanded: false,
      icon: "document",
    }));
    this.setState({nodes: nodesData})
  });
}
```

Then you can generate the label components in your render method

```
public renderLabels() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.nodes.map(n => {
        return (
          <div key={"node-label-" + n.id} onClick={(e) => this.handleScheduleClick(e)}>
            <Tooltip2
              content={n.label.content}
              placement="right"
            >
              {n.label.id}
            </Tooltip2>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

public render() {
  return this.renderLabels());
}
```

Or since you need a custom label component in the nodes array for the Tree component, you can do something like so.

```
public renderNodeLabel(node) {
  return (
    <div key={"node-label-"+node.id} onClick={(e) => this.handleScheduleClick(e)}>
      <Tooltip2
        content={node.label.content}
        placement="right"
      >
        {node.label.id}
      </Tooltip2>
    </div>
  );
}

public render() {
  return (
    <Tree
      contents={this.state.nodes.map(n => ({
        ...n,
        label: this.renderNodeLabel(n),
      }))}
      className="focus-panelsList focus-panelsList-noborder"
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Loading fine now. I will also try to integrate the render label. I am extending an interface from BlueprintJS to populate  the Tree  component. To be honest I am not exactly sure how I can pass that tooltip If I don't create the JSX in the array, not sure how I ca integrate the RenderLabels method that you provided in that Tree component.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Check the third code block

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help @HaseebA. I've got it it work with Drew's suggestion. I will also try yours tomorrow, I am dead beat, it's 3 AM in my country.

Comment: this also worked like a charm. Had to alter a bit the state of the Node, but worked fine. Thanks again!